# html/css: Position shifting with link that increase font size when hovering mouse

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, font-size

I want to make an `html`/`css` menu in my webpage that contain four links (horizontally in top center of page).

and I want the menu link font size to increase when hovering the mouse over (`a:hover`).

but the problem I have is the menu item change its place(down a little) when font size increases (in `IE 8`, and `Chrome`)
and I don't want that to happen, note that I am using a background image (152 * 52) for the link

I tried doing a `table` instead of the `inline-block` but it made a bigger mess.

I also tried playing with `margin` and `padding` which didn't work either.

I am new to html/css so any advice about anything in html/css would be appreciated and forgive my bad english.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home page</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-family:Palatino, ‘Book Antiqua’, Georgia, Garamond, ‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000060;
    background-color: #005070;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu
{
    height:64px;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(img/bglb2.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
}

.menuLink, .menuLink:visited
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(img/btk.png);
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:132px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.menuLink:hover
{
    color:#CC7011;
    background-image:url(img/bto.png);
    font-size: 26px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">
    <a class="menuLink" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="menuLink" href="page1.html">Page1</a>
    <a class="menuLink" href="page2.html">Page2</a>
    <a class="menuLink" href="page3.html">Page3</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect simple solution for this that worked for me on `Chrome`, `IE` and `Firefox` on `win7`.

I put a table with one cell inside the link (`<a>`) that have same `width` and `height` as `<a>` ( which is the image dimensions).

Also made the table: `text-align:center`. The `text-align:center` made sure that the text inside the table will be horizontally centered. and the adavntage of the table is the text will be vertically centered even when font size changes when hovering mouse. Also the table prevented the link image and other links from shifting when font size increases.

I removed all `padding`. Because if I combined (`height`,`width`) with (`padding`), it will produce different results on different browsers (especially `IE` and `Chrome`).

It might be a wrong idea to put stuff inside`<a>` but it did work for most browsers.

I also put this line of code as first line of my html file:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

which made the `<table>` inherit every thing from the link `<a>` which I don't know why but it did simplify stuff.

So resulting code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Home page</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-family:Palatino, ‘Book Antiqua’, Georgia, Garamond, ‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000060;
    background-color: #005070;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu
{
    height:64px;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(img/bglb2.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
}

.menuLink, .menuLink:visited
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(img/btk.png);
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:152px;
    height: 52px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.menuLink:hover
{
    color:#CC7011;
    background-image:url(img/bto.png);
    font-size: 26px;
}

table.ml
{
    text-align: center;
    width:152px;
    height: 52px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">
    <a class="menuLink" href="index.html"><table class="ml"><tr><td>Home</td></tr></table></a>
    <a class="menuLink" href="page1.html"><table class="ml"><tr><td>Page1</td></tr></table></a>
    <a class="menuLink" href="page2.html"><table class="ml"><tr><td>Page2</td></tr></table></a>
    <a class="menuLink" href="page3.html"><table class="ml"><tr><td>Page3</td></tr></table></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a fixed `line-height` to your menu links (for example, `line-height:26px;`).

That way, when you increase the font-size, the height of the line of text will not change. Default value of `line-height` is `normal`, which means the height of each line of your menu will adjust with the font-size.

More information: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond, Your solution seems to be close to fix my case, but I wasn't able to get it right. I tested some values on the `line-height`, `padding` and `margin` but they didn't work out for me. I will test more possibilities..

Comment: Keep on trying different values for line-height until it feels right. It should do the trick. If it doesn't, then I might have misunderstood what the problem is..!

Comment: So, did you manage to fix your problem using `line-height`? If so, don't forget to upvote and accept this answer (for future users who will search for the solution to a similar problem)! If not, post the solution here when you find it!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your css class to solve the problem , here is updated class:

```
.menuLink:hover
{
    color:#CC7011;
    background-image:url(img/bto.png);
    font-size: 26px;
    padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, I tried this before and it messed up the background image for the link

Comment: I have tested it on chrome and firefox on ubuntu and into chrome, firefox and IE on windows7 and its working correctly here

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML Code to

```
 <div class="menu">
 <ul>
   <li><a class="menuLink" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li> <a class="menuLink" href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
   <li><a class="menuLink" href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
   <li><a class="menuLink" href="page3.html">Page3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Add this style

```
 ul,li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
line-height:60px;
vertical-align:bottom;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem some time ago.
I've made a [FIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tztz9/1/) with commented changes for '.menuLink'.

```
.menuLink, .menuLink:visited {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(img/btk.png);
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:132px;
    /* height: 32px; */ /* removed */
    padding: 0 10px; /* changed here */
    line-height: 52px; /* added code */
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* Added code */
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;

    /* In case you have longer 2 words text */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; /* to hide overflowed text */
}
```

Hope this will help other guys, or you can revue your code if my solution is goo